# Any way to get the label from a select item using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of the text in the  tag for the selected item for use in an AJAX request. So for example:

```
<label for="item1">Item Number One</label>
<select name="item1" id="item1" class="lookup">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

I would like to retrieve the text "Item Number One".  Here's the jQuery code that I'm using so far to get the ID and the selected value and post it via AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $(".lookup").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'));
        var selection=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'field=' + id + '&selection=' + selection + '&crudtype=datecheck';
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/processes/steps/autogens/crud",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#" + id + "_date").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You could try `.filter(':selected')`, [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just use the label's `for` attribute to identify it?

So using your example, your jQuery selector would be:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var label = $("label[for='" + id + "']");
var text = label.text();
```

Answer (score 2):

If i'm reading your question correctly you want the text for the selected item/option:

`var selectedOptionText = $('#item1').find(':selected').text();`

To do this within your code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".lookup").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'));
        var selection=$(this).val();
        var selectionText = $(this).find(':selected').text(); //This is the newline.
        var dataString = 'field=' + id + '&selection=' + selection + '&crudtype=datecheck';
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/processes/steps/autogens/crud",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#" + id + "_date").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: "To achieve the best performance when using :selected to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":selected")" from [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), so maybe change find() to filter()?

Comment: @Drops `find` is probably fine here - the docs mean `$('#item1 :selected')` vs `$('#item1').filter(':selected')`

Comment: @Drops Thanks for the suggestion, in this case as the `this` refers to the select element whose only children are option elements there would be no performance advantage with your suggestion. This is a good point normally though. Also directly filtering on this: `$(this).filter(':selected')` would return nothing as the select element itself is not selected one of its child `option` elements is.

Comment: @Neaox answer is right, what I would like suggest is use ´.on()´ instead of ´change()´

Comment: @gon250 `change` is a shortcut for `on('change'): "This method is a shortcut for .on( "change", handler )" - http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @Neaox I think you are wrong, you can see in the link you sent me using change() is an alias to bind('change' ...). take a look: `$('select').change()` will only apply to all <select> before this is called, and `$('select').on('change')` provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

Comment: @gon250 `change(function(){...})` does indeed use `on` rather than `bind`,  `on` does not behave the way you seem to think it does. `$('select').on('change', function(){...})` will not automatically pick up and be binded to new select elements when they are added to the dom, to do that you would want to attach the `change` listener to the document and then use a selector filter: `$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){...});` I have made a jsfiddle to show this: https://jsfiddle.net/80bbuyqq/

Comment: @gon250 You may have been looking at the description on that page which does use the term 'Bind', however in this context it is a term rather than a function name.

If you look at the next paragraph (below the table) it says the following: 
"This method is a shortcut for .on( "change", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "change" ) in the third.".

Comment: @Neaox I understand what you said and I appreciate your explanation but I still thinking is different use `on()` . take a look this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3hp0gsex/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73627/discussion-between-neaox-and-gon250).

Answer (score 0):

**Go for the `ID`-vs-`FOR` attributes search**:

```
$(".lookup").change(function() {

    var labelText = $("[for="+this.id+"]").text(); // You have the LABEL's text now
    // other code here...

});
```

P.S: Taking in consideration that one day someone (not you) could modify the HTML and put LABEL wherever one thinks it fits best, it's not a good idea to lookup for `.closest()` (specially if it's not a parent :) ) or use `.prev()`, `.next()` etc...

Answer (score -1):

Use DOM traversal to get the text node from the `<label>` element, i.e.

```
var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
```

Like this (and you have an extra closing parenthesis at the end of the third line):

```
$(function() {
    $(".lookup").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id'),
            selection = $(this).val(),
            labelText = $(this).prev('label').text(),
            dataString = 'field=' + id + '&selection=' + selection + '&crudtype=datecheck';
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/processes/steps/autogens/crud",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#" + id + "_date").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

p/s: You can concatenate `var` declarations with a comma :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the label and the select aren't always direct peers I'd go for this inside the change callback

```
var curName = $(this).attr('name');
var labelText = $('[for='+curName+']').text();
```

This will generically get the text for the label associated with the select via the `for` and `name` attrs.

This still isn't the best way to go about these things, you should never treat the DOM as data. At the least, when you construct the select you can use a `data-` tag for quicker/better lookup.

Comment: Note that the `for` attribute points at an element by ID - you'd be better off reading the ID rather than the name, just in case they're not the same.